# how can I know which option is clicked on in a select tag while updating a variable in the ts file?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this simple select that is generating the numbers from an array in the `component.ts` file and I want to make it so that when the user clicks a number on the dropdown list, a variable in that `.ts` file is updated (`inputBoxes`) and that many input boxes will be displayed.

in my html file I have

component.html

```
<p>How many words will you be using?</p>
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let num of wordCount" (click)="updateInputBoxes(num)">{{num}}</option>
</select>
```

component.ts

```
  public wordCount: Array<number> = [1,2,3,4,5];
  public inputBoxes: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  updateInputBoxes(num: number) {
    this.inputBoxes = num;
  }
```

This is what I was trying so far but the `updateInputBoxes` function doesn't even execute. How do I know which number is selected while sending that selected number as a parameter to the function `updateInputBoxes`?

Answer (score 1):

Use template driven or reactive forms for this.
The template driven version looks like this:

```html
<select name="countControl" [(ngModel)]="inputBoxes">
  <option *ngFor="let wordCount of wordCounts" [ngValue]="wordCount">
    {{ wordCount }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Docs: https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#description

Answer (score 1):

You need to add change method in select tag then pass the event to get current selected option vaule in ts file.

Try this code to get selected option value :

**HTML CODE**

```
 <select (change)="updateInputBoxes($event)">
            <option value="">
              Select count
            </option>
            <option *ngFor="let num of wordCount" value={{num}}>{{num}}</option>
 </select>
```

**TS CODE**

```
updateInputBoxes(event) {
    this.inputBoxes = event.target.value;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call method after select each options you need to use `change` event in `select` tag not **option** tag.

And to pass selected value to your methods you can use `template reference` like this:

```
<select #selectList (change)="updateInputBoxes(selectList.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let num of wordCount" [value]="num">{{num}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is working sample I created: [StackBlitzLink](https://stackblitz.com/edit/thinkster-hello-world-4yruz2-gnnuyc-a8wj9z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

But if you only need selected value of `selectbox` there is no need to call fanction just use `[(ngModel)]="inputBoxes"` like this:

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="inputBoxes">
   <option *ngFor="let num of wordCount" [value]="num">{{num}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @JDoe3898 Has your problem been solved? let me know if still there is a problem

Comment: yes this answer solves my problem. Thank you so much

Comment: @JDoe3898 you are welcome. Could you please accept me if my answer helps you?